# While loop and json

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter-typeahead

I am working with Twitter Typeahead [prefetch](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch) to search a (json) list of books.

I need to create an array of objects which contains both the `title` of the book and the `publication_date` - I'm just not sure how! I've only managed to get the title so far.

The code I have at present works, however it only returns the book title, I'm not sure what I have to change in order to also retrieve the publication_date.

Maybe I need a foreach instead of a while loop? Quite new to this and learning as I go.

My code at present;

```
<?php
include(URL. '/lib/conn.php'); // include the db connection

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM publication");

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = utf8_encode($row['title']);
}

file_put_contents(URL . '/title.json', json_encode($data)); 

?>
```

The code above successfully creates a `title.json` and populates it with a list of book titles.

Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = array('title' => utf8_encode($row['title']),
                    'date'  => $row['publication_date']);
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Peftect @Linesofcode thank you! Could you maybe briefly explain what I was doing wrong in your answer?

Comment: @johnny_s You just forgot to pass the param `date`, and in order to accomplish that (carry two or more params) you need to create an array.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would just select the rows you need from the database:

```
SELECT title, publication_date FROM publication
```

This will a) limit the bandwidth of data you are sending and b) make your life easier when fetching results and assigning to data structure.

```
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row; // just assign each row to the $data array
}

file_put_contents(URL . '/title.json', json_encode($data));
```

Also, if your content if utf-8 encoded in the DB, there is no reason to encode it before display.